# CodeIgniter database retrieval issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my first attempt to code in CodeIgniter. The problem is it's not able to retrieve data from the database. The error it's throwing is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Site::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51
```

I could understand what to change in that line of `core/model.php`.

And this is the another error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\CI_one\application\models\site_model.php on line 9
```

#### Controller

```
<?php
    class Site extends CI_Controller {
        function datta(){
            $this->load->model('site_model');
            $get = $this->site_model->getValues();
            $data['get'] = $get;
            $this->load->view('data3',$data);
        }
    }
```

#### Model

```
<?php
    class site_model extends CI_Model{

        function index(){
            echo "default index";
        }

        function getValues(){
            $query = $this->db->query("select * from nav_menu");

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
               foreach ($query->result() as $row)
               {
                  echo $row->c1;
                  echo $row->m2;
                  echo $row->d3;
               }
            }
            return array(
                "name" => "nameless",
                "form" => "formless",
                "age"  => "ageless");
        }
    }
```

I've set database parameters in `app/config/database.php`.

How do I make this work?

---

I solved it myself. I wiped off and recoded as follows to get the result...

#### Controller

```
<?php
    class Site extends CI_Controller {
        function datta(){

            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('site_model');
            $get = $this->site_model->getValues();
            $data['get'] = $get;
            $this->load->view('data3',$data);
        }
    }
```

Model as

```
<?php
    class site_model extends CI_Model{

        function index(){
            echo "default index";
        }

        function getValues(){
            $query = $this->db->query("select * from nav_menu");

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
               foreach ($query->result() as $row)
               {
                  echo $row->c1;
                  echo $row->m2;
                  echo $row->d3;
               }
            }
            return array(
                "name" => "nameless",
                "form" => "formless",
                "age"  => "ageless");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Open config/autoload.php, and check that array $autoload['libraries'] contains 'database'

Comment: @Adeel added $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); as suggested but thrown an error like this 
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: database

Comment: How are you calling the controller ? Mention the complete URL. Don't try to echo things from model. Use the view for it. Check your `database.php` and check if database configurations are proper.

Comment: like http://localhost/CI_one/index.php/site/datta am calling, just to check i've echo'ed in model. db config is proper, added db in auto load library, tried making $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; as false in app/config/db still not working @SilentAssassin

Comment: @gurudev I have updated my answer please check it out!

Comment: @sandip thanks bro :) dont know logics but somehow its working now, look at my edit

Comment: @gurudev it's because you have loaded $this->load->database(); now and you have not loaded before edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Codeigniter you have to manually load the DB library like below:

```
$this->load->database();
```

Or you have to auto load the library as told by sandip.

During your application you may need several libraries and helpers to be autoloaded, so instead of manually loading them, the auto load is the best practice. Kindly read about auto loading here.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html

Also read the rest of the documentation, and you will learn all about CI from there. It is easy, concise and have examples.

Hope this will help.

Comment: $this->load->database('mydb'); this is wrong, just use $this->load->database();.

Comment: tried, yet the same error, do i need to mention db name somewhere else other than app/config/database.php

Comment: may be u r right, adding this line and clearing my browser's head produced result. sorry cant voteup u as i dont have enough reputation. thanks

Comment: no problem. Thats good your issue is fixed. Before you go ahead, try to give some time to CI documentation, and when you need any feature, just look at CI documentation and you will find it, and follow their way of work.

Answer (score 0):

Please write a **constructor** in the CodeIgniter controller as:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

And in addition to this:

You have to load the database library first. In

autoload.php:

```
  $autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```

Or in the controller constructor as:

```
  $this->load->database();
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: both ended up showing 

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: database

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

Controller :

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller {
    function datta(){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('site_model');
        $get=$this->site_model->getValues();
        $data['get']=$get;
        $this->load->view('data3',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: still same error! if i try to place db name as parameter in   $this->load->database(); its saying 
An Error Was Encountered

You have specified an invalid database connection group.